# Trying to generate username Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

Before I start I should mention i'm a complete novice and I apologise if this code is horrific.

I'm trying to create a username using first initial and surname to be ouputted with a welcome message of "hello Username, welcome to myfunction!".

I'm suppose to use a string to attach the initial and surname together then concatenate the first character of string 1 with string 2 and store the username.

any help would be appreciated as this is for school.

here's what I have so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type = "text/javascript">

// GenerateUsername Function
function GenerateUsername ()
{

    var x;

    var firstInitial = prompt("Please enter your initial of your first name");
    var surName = prompt("please enter your surname");

    var user = new Array();

    firstInitial [0] = "user";
    surName [1] ="user";

    document.write(firstInitial + surName);

}

if (user == 0)
{
    alert("welcome, " + user);
}

</script>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You have lots of errors, and you don't call your function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might can help you. return value from function call and then bind in alert

```
function GenerateUsername ()
{

var x;

var firstInitial = prompt("Please enter your initial of your first name");
var surName = prompt("please enter your surname");

var user = new Array();

firstInitial [0] = "user";
surName [1] ="user";

return firstInitial[0] + ' ' + surName[1];

}

if (user == 0)
{
    alert("welcome, " + GenerateUserName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call your function when your page is loaded you have to add the attribute onload="GenerateUsername()" on a html tag. 
Also you should place your javascript in a different file and comment your code (it is easy to understand it but if you're a total beginner in javascript you will probably not remember what's the difference between prompt and alert in some days for example).